# Why doesn't the landing of birds on powerlines ever lead to sparks like a Van der Graaf generator?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

I saw a Van der Graaf generator spark when a demonstrator touched it.  I believe the voltage was 600 kV which is in the range of high voltage power lines.  Other discussions about birds on power lines have emphasized that the bird is safe because it isn't completing a circuit to ground.

I've never heard of powerlines arcing to the bird.  I know that the belt of the Van der Graaf generator is transferring charge onto the dome, whereas the power lines are electrically neutral. But I don't think I'm totally understanding the reason why the Van der Graaf generator arcs while the power line doesn't, since they are both of high voltage.

Comment: Yes, but your demonstrator is still standing on the ground (earth) when touching it. Birds are never in contact with the earth (while on power lines). Whether it's power lines or a Van Der Graaff generator, current will flow from higher to lower potential/earth.

Comment: Potential difference between a bird and the line is rather different from that between the line and the earth. See discussion in the duplicated question.

Answer (score 2):

*I saw a Van de Graaff generator spark when a demonstrator touched it.* should read *I saw a Van de Graaff generator spark $\color{red}{\text{just before the}}$ demonstrator touched it.*

What happened was that the electric field strength between the VdG and the demonstrator was high enough to ionise (breakdown)  the air which produced a conducting path between the VdG and the demonstrator and this resulted in the spark.

In general when birds are sitting on high voltage power lines the electric field between them and adjacent power lines is not sufficient to produces sparking but there may be a [corona discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge) from pointed parts of the bird eg the pointed beak oe end of wing feathers which produces an insufficient conducting path to cause the bird permanent harm.

Of course if the bird is sufficiently large the gap between the bird and the adjacent power line may be sufficient small for the air to ionise which a result as in the photograph below.

[image]

Engineers who design high voltage power lines are well aware of the problems that birds may cause both to the bird itself and to the power line which would temporarily trip if the air around the cables becomes conducting to a significant degree.

Here is a diagram of the sort of size parameters which engineers use when designing power lines.

[image]

The paper [Bird protection on medium voltage power lines](http://cired.net/publications/cired2015/papers/CIRED2015_1288_final.pdf) gives an indication
care taken to avoid harm to birds during the design process.